# Z-Tree: Hyperlinks

Tags: ztree

Does anybody know if it's possible to add a hyperlink into a Z-Tree questionnaire. The functionality of google forms is more optimal, in my opinion, and I want to skip the address form and directly link to a google forms, as a conclusion to the experiment.

I've tried including a text program directly into the "new question form." The problem is, Z-Tree locks down the browser which makes me think that a hyperlink is inherently dissuaded by the software.

I don't think it's possible, but confirmation of this would be much appreciated!